# Can cloud9 IDE use vim plugins?

Tags: cloud9-ide

If I use Cloud9 IDE with Vim mode can I install vim plugins? I cannot tell how to install plugins from messing around with the IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Although Cloud9 does have it's own SDK and plugin development program which is currently in Alpha, so many Vim plugins will be ported to it soon. You can learn more and suggest plugin ideas at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cloud9-sdk